# XenServer High Availability

Tags: high-availability, xenserver

I was wondering if anyone has ever tried to setup HA-like functionality without paying for the Essentials Package using XenServer. I love XenServer but would rather not fork over $2.5k per server for the Essentials Package.

Also, is the HA that comes with the Essentials Package worth it when compared to the time it would take me to script a custom HA package?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. I know you can set this up using Xen and Heartbeat but that's not my question :-)

Comment: Your question makes no sense... you want to know about alternatives to Essentials, but then you rule out answers related to alternatives.

Comment: It's makes plenty of sense.  I wasn't ruling out heartbeat totally, the only key here is that is must be based on XenServer and not just Xen(Source).

Comment: I was trying to save people from saying, "Scrap XenServer and just use Xen and heartbeat", that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question:

Without lots of custom scripts it's not possible.  My final solution was Xen and Xen Cloud:

http://xen.org/products/cloudxen.html